# Является ли функция operator# статической по умолчанию?

Tags: c++

Я использовал перегрузку оператора в виде функции, где она является членом класса:

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  class loc{
    int longitude, latitude;
  public:
    loc();
    loc(int lg, int lt){
    longitude = lg;
    latitude = lt;
   }
   void show(){
       cout << longitude << " " << latitude << endl;
   }
   loc operator+(loc op2);
   loc operator-(loc op2);
   loc operator=(loc op2);
   loc oprator++();
 };

 loc loc::operator+(loc op2){
      loc  temp;
      temp.latitude = latitude + op2.latitude;
      temp.longitude = longitude + op2.longitude;
      return temp;
 }

  loc loc::operator-(loc op2){
       loc  temp;
   temp.latitude = latitude - op2.latitude;
   temp.longitude = longitude - op2.longitude;
   return temp;
  }

  loc loc::operator=(loc op2){
   latitude = op2.latitude;
   longitude = op2.longitude;
   return *this;
  }

  loc loc::operator++(){

 longitude = longitude++;
 latitude = latitude++;
 return *this;
  }

  int main()
  {
     loc ob1(10, 20), ob2(4, 50);
     ob1.show();
     ob2.show();
     ++ob1;
     ob1.show();
     ob1 = ob2;
     cin.get();
     return 0;
  }
```

На что дебагер ругается:

> main.cpp(44): error C2355: this: может указываться только в
>   нестатических членах-функциях

Хотя явно она(функция) не указана как static: .
Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, весь код. На первый взгляд не вполне правильная перегрузка префиксного оператора: `loc& loc::operator++()`

Answer (score 2):

Для начала исправьте определение префиксного оператора ++ ([Operators in C/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)) так:

```
loc& loc::operator++()
```

Answer (score 1):

Без явного указания слова `static` в объявлении функции-члена, независимо от того является ли эта функция перегруженным оператором или нет, она не будет считаться статической.

Упомянутая ошибка

> error C2355: this: может указываться только в нестатических
>   членах-функциях

судя по всему возникла из-за опечатки в объявлении оператора `loc oprator++();` (пропущена буква `e`). Что в свою очередь привело к тому, что определение

```
loc loc::operator++() {

    longitude = longitude++;
    latitude = latitude++;
    return *this;
}
```

было воспринято компилятором (а не дебаггером), как функция, не имеющая отношения к классу `loc`. Т.е. помимо упомянутой ошибки должны были быть и другие.

Если устранить опечатку и добавить реализацию конструктора по умолчанию, код будет [собираться](http://rextester.com/FZOF19051). Но это ещё не значит, что в нём всё хорошо.

---

### Проблемы кода

1. Как уже было упомянуто в другом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/114850/176217), каноническая форма
   оператора префиксного инкремента должна возвращать ссылку на текущий
   объект.
2. Бинарные операторы `+` и `-` следует сделать свободными функциями-друзьями (не членами). При этом кол-во явных параметров (которые надо бы передавать как `const loc&`) в них увеличится:

   ```
   friend loc operator+(const loc& lhs, const loc& rhs);
   ```
3. Саму реализацию можно упростить:

   ```
   loc loc::operator+(const loc& lhs, const loc& rhs) {
         return loc(lhs.longitude + rhs.longitude, lhs.latitude + rhs.latitude);
   }
   ```

   Дополнительно это приводит к тому, что пропадает необходимость в конструкторе по умолчанию.
4. Явный оператор копирующего присваивания не нужен, т.к. версия предоставленная системой выполнит почленное копирование за вас.
5. В существующей реализации префиксного инкремента (с учетом исправления сигнатуры) присутствует ошибка множественного неупорядоченного (unsequenced) изменения данных. Ошибки такого рода согласно Стандарту языка приводят к неопределенному поведению (UB). Исправленная версия оператора префиксного инкремента могла бы выглядеть так:

   ```
   loc& loc::operator++() {
       ++longitude;
       ++latitude;
       return *this;
   }
   ```
6. Функции-члены, не изменяющие видимого состояния объекта, должны быть объявлены как `const`:

   ```
   void show() const;
   ```
7. Инициализацию полей класса правильнее делать в инициализаторе (а не теле) конструктора:

   ```
   loc(int lg, int lt) : longitude(lg), latitude(lt) {}
   ```